# Show that F is differentiable at $x_0$ iff f is continuous at $x_0$

Tags: integration, analysis, derivatives

I have the task to show that: "F is differentiable at $x_0$ iff f is continuous at $x_0$" given that: Let a<b $\in \mathbb{R}$ and f: [a,b] $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$ a monotone increasing function. Further let F:[a,b] $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$ be the function $F(x) := \int_{[a,b]}f$ and $x_0 \in [a,b]$.

I think I can show that: $F'(x_0) \rightarrow f(x_0)$ and that $f(x_0)$ is continuous by using the first fundamental theorem of analysis: Since f is monotone increasing on a bounded intervall, it follows that f is Riemann integrable. It is given that $F(x) := \int_{[a,b]}f(x)dx$ and hence the first fundamental theorem directly applies from which follows that $F(x)$ is continuous $\forall x \in [a,b]$ and $F'(x_0) = f(x_0)$.

Though, showing the other direction, that is, that $f(x_0) \rightarrow F'(x_0)$ if f is continuous at $x_0$ is not clear for me so far. My approach would be to start assuming that f is not continuous at some point and then try to build on this. Though I am stuck here.

Comment: $F'(x_0) \rightarrow f(x_0)$ does not make sense. Also, there is a typo in the definition of $F(x)$.

Comment: I think the definition of $\;F\;$ must be $$F(x):=\int_a^{x} f(t)\,dt\;,\;\;x\in [a,b]$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\;f\;$ is continuous and let $\;x_0\in[a,b]\;$.  Then for any $\;\epsilon>0\;$ there exists $\;\delta>0\;$ such that $\;|x-x_0|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon\;$ . For simplicity assume $\;x>x_0\;\;$(so we're going to use one sided limits).

$$\left|\frac{F(x)-F(x_0)}{x-x_0}-f(x_0)\right|=\frac1{x-x_0}\left|\int_{x_0}^xf(t)\,dt-f(x_0)(x-x_0)\right|=$$

$$=\frac1{x-x_0}\left|\int_{x_0}^x \left(f(t)-f(x_0)\right)dx\right|\le\frac1{x-x_0}\int_{x_0}^x \left|f(t)-f(x_0)\right|dx<\frac1{x-x_0}\int_{x_0}^x\epsilon\,dt=\epsilon$$

and this proves $\;F'(x_0)\;$ exists and equals $\;f(x_0)\;$ (you do the other one sided limit if you want to.)

Now check again your own other direction because it looks pretty suspicious...